# Is there a way to use PC/SC in web application or extensions without using middlewares?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps, smartcard, google-chrome-os, pcsc

I'm trying to use smartcards in web environment, but I'm unable to find a way for doing it rather than using middlewares to pass the data to my extension or PWA. The target application for reading smartcards is smart card connector of chromeOS, but it's deprecated and I can't use it in manifest v3.

Is there a way for implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it through java script like what have been done [here](https://github.com/WICG/web-smart-card).